# How To Limit Java App To Single Instance : Launch4j maven plugin

Tags: java, maven-plugin, launch4j

I am building a java app and is converted to exe using launch4j maven plugin. Is there any configuration in launch4j that allows it to have only a single instance.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is a configuration in launch4j.  The option is called "singleInstance".  Set that to be true.  This will make sure only one instance at a time will be executed.

```
<singleInstance>true</singleInstance>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**, launch4j has a configuration option called `singleInstance` that allows you to specify whether the application should allow only one instance to run at a time. This option can be set to `true` in the launch4j configuration to prevent multiple instances of the application from running simultaneously. To enable this behaviour, just put this in `build/plugins/plugin` section of your `pom.xml` file to configure the plugin with single instance:

```
<configuration>
   <singleInstance>true</singleInstance>
</configuration>
```